# Memory efficient way to modify XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xsd, xml-parsing

I need to modify a single information in XML file . XML file is about 100 lines . For modifying a single element in whole XML file what would be the most memory efficient way in JAVA ?

1. JAXB is better ?
2. Simple SAX parser ?

or any other way .....Kindly suggest .....

Comment: I have to change that single node information in an XML file . But the count of those XML file can be huge around 5000  to 10000 in for loop .

Answer (score 1):

SAX parser gives more control on parsing and is faster than DOM parser. JAXB will be easy from the sense of less code writing. XStream is also another option but that is similar to JAXB which is a high level API, so it has some overhead task so it will be bit slower then SAX. 
I will not suggest for direct string manipulation (applying String.indexOf() and String.replace()) although would be fastest way for updating a unique tag in the XML but its risky as your XML might not be valid and if xml structure is not simple then there will be risk of updating wrong level tag :-)

Therefore, SAX parser looks the best bet to me.

Comment: Writing SAX applications is difficult, it requires a high level of skill and a large amount of time. Although the answer to the question is correct, I'm very reluctant to recommend SAX to anyone unless I'm confident that they really need it, and that they have the skills to use it. We get a lot of questions here from people trying to use SAX who don't even know how to implement a simple Stack.

Comment: Thanks Michael - Its truly an honor to see your reply here. I have always been a big fan of yours.  !

Answer (score 1):

Your files are not big. The memory used to hold a 100-line XML file costs about as much as 5 milliseconds of a programmer's time. I would question your requirement: why do you need to do it in "the most memory efficient way"? I would use XSLT or JDOM2, unless there is clear quantified information that this will not meet externally-imposed performance requirement, which cannot be solved by buying a bit more memory.

Comment: I agree . May be my my individual files are not huge in size but the count of such files are huge or can be huge while I update each and every XMl file in loop . Count of such files can grow up to 30000-60000 also . That why I am concerned about performance. I am eagerly waiting for your valuable suggestion if u have any more on this topic  .

Comment: Sure you should be concerned about performance. But not memory. Each document will presumably be garbage collected as soon as it has been processed.

Comment: Can I use JAXB for loading XML and update XML . Will that going to be more performance efficient that normal SAX parser ?

Comment: JAXB can be very efficient. It works best, in my experience, when the structure of the XML files is simple, regular and stable. If there's a lot of variation between different documents, or if the structure is going to change over time, then JAXB isn't your best option.